# want to create add PDF Merger in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am new in laravel currently i have task which is based on  PDF ..

Like :

Mearge PDF

Create PDF ,

Convert PDF etc.

But problem is this when i am search on google than there is PDF merger but i don't know how to configure PDF merger or any other Github code in laravel.

Please help. I am always appreciate.

Thanks

Link where i found some code : https://github.com/clegginabox/pdf-merger

```
$pdf = new \Clegginabox\PDFMerger\PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', '1, 3, 4');
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', '1-2');
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all');

//You can optionally specify a different orientation for each PDF
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', '1, 3, 4', 'L');
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', '1-2', 'P);

$pdf->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf', 'P');

// REPLACE 'file' WITH 'browser', 'download', 'string', or 'file' for output options
// Last parameter is for orientation (P for protrait, L for Landscape). 
// This will be used for every PDF that doesn't have an orientation specified
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you just need to add "clegginabox/pdf-merger": "dev-master" to your composer.json in the "require" section found in your laravel project base path. And than run composer update from your console. If you haven't configured composer read through https://getcomposer.org/ and or listen to https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch its free.

Answer (score 0):

i actually use this one:

https://github.com/LynX39/lara-pdf-merger/blob/master/README.md

if you need more help please let me know